# IIS worker process (w3wp.exe) shoots to 99% CPU when WCF service is invoked

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-6

We have a .NET 3.5 WCF service hosted on IIS 6.0 which has a basicHttp binding. This is consumed by 2 .NET and 2 ASP applications. When the 4th application (irrespective of .NET or ASP) is started and tries consuming it, the w3wp.exe peaks at 99% and stays there after few seconds.

Based on this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2008/04/21/wcf-request-throttling-and-server-scalability.aspx), we tried adding the following to the .NET 2.0 machine.config but this does not have any effect.

```
<processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="500" maxIoThreads="500" minWorkerThreads="2"/>
<httpRuntime minFreeThreads="250" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="250"/>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Added the crash analysis report info:

Warning 1: The following threads in w3wp.exe_*v2.0 Applications*_PID_*2856*_Date__12_08_2011__Time_12_13_39PM_*876*_Manual Dump.dmp are waiting on a synchronous WCF request to execute
4.35% of threads blocked

Please click on the Actual Thread to see the desnitation WCF Thread or check WCF Request report to find out the thread id for the actual WCF thread for which this thread is waiting on. For more details on this WCF Behavior check out the blog on WCF Request Throttling and Server Scalability.

```
Thread 16 - System ID 3920
Entry point   mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::intermediateThreadProc 
Create time   12/8/2011 12:10:44 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.031 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.140 

This thread is waiting on a synchronous WCF request to execute

The destination WCF Thread for this ASP.NET worker thread is 14


.NET Call Stack
Function 
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean) 
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int64, Boolean) 
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean) 
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne() 
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(System.Web.HttpApplication, Boolean) 
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(System.Object, System.EventArgs) 
System.Web.HttpApplication+SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef) 
System.Web.HttpApplication+ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception) 
System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object) 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest) 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest) 
System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr, Int32)
```

Comment: To try to isolate IIS processing from the work your WCF service does, creating a Windows Service hosted version of your service and see if it exhibits the same behavior under a similar load. If it does then there is CPU intensive work being trigger by the load in your service. If not, then you know you have an IIS optimization issue which might be fixed by moving to IIS 7 :)

Comment: @SixtoSaez: That seems like a good idea but converting it to a Windows service (or moving to IIS 7) would be impractical at this stage considering its size. I was hoping this could be more about a thread management issue about the way the ASP.NET worker threads talk to the WCF IO threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your load is somehow generating a lot of threads and thereby causing the CPU to work like crazy to keep up with them. Since your edit references a crash dump, you may be able to use WinDbg to find out what is going on.

If you're familiar with WinDbg and have it already installed and configured ([otherwise spend some quality time with the tutorials here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx)) , try the following:

```
.loadby sos mscorwks
.prefer_dml 1
!threads
```

This will show how many threads were created. The `.prefer_dml 1` enables HTML like links to be generated so you can just click to run an appropriate command in the output. Next run:

```
!syncblk
```

to see which threads may be blocked. It should [show which thread](http://dotnetdebug.net/2006/02/23/syncblk-in-sos-for-net-framework-20/) is doing the blocking. Next run something like this to get the stack for thread 32 if that one were the culprit:

```
~32e!clrstack
```

It should contain information on the code running on that thread which is doing the blocking. Saying working with WinDbg is very archane is a enormous understatement but it is worth the effort to help debug issues like yours. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have not used WinDbg (in the process of getting it) but if it just shows the blocking thread and its stack trace, isn't that what I have in my OP. I know Thread 16 is the culprit and from the .NET stack trace, `HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous` is doing the waiting for the IO thread 14. I just am not sure what the IO thread is doing. Would WinDbg help in that aspect?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me which thread the stack trace in the question belonged to. If the stack trace is for thread 16 then its waiting on something (thread 14?) itself. Otherwise, look at the stack trace for thread 14 to see what it is doing. Hopefully, the !syncblk output should help determining any threads that are involved in a deadlock. This is where using WinDbg really helps assuming you know which spell to cast.